# Запись iso на USB в Linux через консоль.

Tags: usb, консоль, linux

Нужно через консоль. GUI-приложения подвели.
Есть образы Windows, хочу рядом установить с Linux.

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, вдруг получится

```
dd if=/path/to/windows.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Где /dev/sdb - ваша флешка, вероятно потребуются права рута.

Comment: вроде можно сначала замонитровать iso, а потом dd из маунт поинта на флешку

Comment: можно и без монтирования. только потом нужно флэху сделать загрузочной через fdisk, cfdisk, etc.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что при такой записи получится корректный загрузочный образ Windows

Answer (score 0):

[Запись образа Windows 7 на USB из Linux](http://dig.org.ua/2010/11/29/windows-7-on-usb-from-linux/)

Comment: не. ms-sys нет ни на серваках ни у меня на компе :(
поищу мож еще где...

Comment: А что у Вас за дистрибутив?

PS - ms-sys скачать можно тут: http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/#Download

Comment: у меня два - виста и ХР третий пак блэк эдишн.

Comment: Ссылка в ответе битая, как результат, в настоящее время ответ бесполезен. Поэтому рекомендуется отражать существенную информацию непосредственно в самом ответе, чтобы избежать подобных ситуаций.

Answer (score 0):

форматируешь флешку с параметром бут , мотритуешь образ и копируешь банально все содержимое образа